# How do I get the ID column (& other columns) that do not have the same value in the city column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT61l.png

I would like the result from a query to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cccus.png

Could someone help me out? Essentially all I am trying to do is not get ids where all city values for the same id is NOT Miami.

I have tried a couple of group by/having(sum) and also tried where not exists. But I can't get an answer what I want.

In BigQuery doing where not exists, I get this error:

> Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into efficient JOIN.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from your_table
where true 
qualify count(*) over win != countif(city =  'Miami') over win
window win as (partition by id)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Here `count(*) over win != countif(city =  'Miami') over win` is literally translated as `where all city values for the same id is NOT Miami`

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up the answer :o)